# Create Installation Script using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I need to create a PowerShell script to install some applications/ software silently at startup on Windows without manual intervention. I am new to PowerShell and got below script created via some lift and shift on google. But When executing PowerShell via command line, the application installation does not start. Can someone help in identifying another approach on what needs to be added in below script?

```
        $app1name = "App1"
        $app1skip = "no"
        $app1path = "C:\Users\"
        $app1runcommand = "W7W10_Install"
        $app1arguments = ""
        $datetime = Get-Date -format "yyyy.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss"
        $logpath = "C:\Users\$datetime"
        New-Item -Path $logpath -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $VerbosePreference="Continue"

        #Transcript Start
       Start-Transcript -Path $logpath


       $startlogtime = Get-Date -format "HH:mm:ss"
       write-host "Script Start Time - $startlogtime"


       #Install Applications
       #Application 1
       if ($app1skip -eq "no") {
     if ($app1arguments) { #Arguments Variable Populated
        Write-Host Installing Applcation 1 `($app1name`)
        $app1 = Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $app1path$app1runcommand -ErrorAction Continue - 
      ArgumentList $app1arguments -WindowStyle Normal
            if ($app1.ExitCode -eq "0") {
                Write-Host $app1name Installed ok
                } Else {
                    Write-host $app1name install exited with code $app1.ExitCode
                    } 
                }
            }Else { #Argurments Variable Empty
                Write-Host Installing Applcation 1 `($app1name`)
                $app1 = Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $app1path$app1runcommand -ErrorAction Continue - 
                WindowStyle Normal
                if ($app1.ExitCode -eq "0") {
                    Write-Host $app1name Installed ok
                    } Else {
                        Write-host $app1name install exited with code $app1.ExitCode
                }
            }

            #Transcript End
                 Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Can you narrow the issue down? Your code is quite long and hard to comprehend.

Comment: Actually I need to create a process to install one application when machine is build newly.  Manually when we install an application it give option to click next and next on windows. I need to install that application at machine reboot using powershell silentely without any one manual intervention. Hope this explain scenario . I

Comment: I meant, go through your code, verify which parts work and which part does not work. Then provide us with the failing part and we will have a look at it.